# Laravel: render templates in database

Tags: php, templates, laravel

My Laravel app allows users to modify email templates, then save them to database.

Sample:

> Customer {{ $customer_name }} has accepted your proposed timing {{ $timing }} for PO {{ $po_no }}

*(User can change 'customer' to 'client' etc.. but leave the {{ }} intact )*

The app then loads dynamic data below into above template.

> $data = array('customer_email'=> "email@mail.com",
>                   'timing'=> "2pm",'po_no' => "PO001"
>               );

Then email those rendered text to some emails.

## How can I do that?

Rephrase:

1. load text from db
2. make it a Blade template
3. render that template with data

I get stuck at #2

Comment: Can't you use `View::render()`?

Comment: @Ravan, how? Laravel only accepts filed-views?

Comment: Not possible without `eval()` and I wouldn't wanna go down that road...

Comment: My solution so far: Save the customizable templates into view files.

Answer (score 0):

add email view to your views/emails folder
ex: **mail_template.blade.php**

```
Customer {{ $customer_name }} has accepted your proposed
 timing {{ $timing }} for PO {{ $po_no }}
```

**send method**

```
Mail::send('emails.mail_template', array('customer_email'=> "email@mail.com", 'timing'=> "2pm",'po_no' => "PO001" ), function($message)
            {
                $message->to('sendto@gmail.com')->subject('your email subject');
            });
```

further read [Official Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage)

Comment: instead of using array('customer_email'=> "email@mail.com".....) you can use your pre defined array 
$data

Comment: You mean, create **mail_template.blade.php** file, then store the db template inside?